# Issue with running JavaScript while using HttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

The basis of what I'm trying to do store paths in a mySQL then images on the server. Then using the PHP code below load them onto the screen and move through them using a button. This is fine on the browser. However these actions will actually be done on a cordova app which doesn't accept PHP. I've been getting around this factor by using HTTP Request. Loading the elements into a div. Unfortunately HTML elements to do load from the PHP file. However the JavaScript functions don't work. Not even alerts and especially not the function used to load the first and follow images into an array and display them.

Below is my code from the PHP side which I'm trying to display using HTTP Request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<?php
include("mysqlconnect.php");

$select_query = "SELECT `ImagesPath` FROM `offerstbl` ORDER by `ImagesId` DESC";
$sql = mysql_query($select_query) or die(mysql_error());   
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){
$data[] = $row['ImagesPath'];
}

$images = json_encode($data);

?>

<script> 

var images = <?php echo $images; ?>

alert(images[1]);


var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
  var img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = images[index];
  document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
}

function changeImage(){
  var img = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
  index++;
  index = index % images.length; // This is for if this is the last image then goto first image
  img.src = images[index];
}
</script>




<body onload="buildImage();">
<div class="contents" id="content"></div>
<button onclick="changeImage()">NextImage</button>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the HTML code in the cordova I've been using to display the PHP code. However none of my JavaScript functions work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("phpFile").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","http:server/content.php?");
        xmlhttp.send();

    }


    </head>

    <body onload="showUser()">

    <div class="contents" id="phpFile">


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @user3889508 In your cordova html file you are using an AJAX call. The AJAX call will not run the <script> tag that you sending thru **PHP** processing routine. If you want to run a script that you should be using JSONP.

Comment: @frank: is the conversion from this AJAX to JSONP simple enough or is it quite a long process? What would it look like?

Comment: @user3889508 I would suggest better to use a library like jquery (Or whichever you are comfortable with), which will handle quirks in various browser implementation. As you can see yourself that you have use code for IE7+ etc. Libraries will handle that for you.

Comment: If anyone could begin the process of converting the AJAX above to JSONP that would be very grateful.